# Validation of complex objects weirdness

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is for Blazor server.

I have complex objects in my page. So the properties are (just showing the key parts):

```
public class ProfilePageModel : IIncludesAddressModel
{
    [ValidateComplexType]
    public AddressFormPageModel AddressModel { get; set; }

    [NoSeparator]
    [Required]
    public string? TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class AddressFormPageModel
{
    [Required]
    public string? StreetNumberAndName { get; set; }

    public string? SuiteApt { get; set; }
}
```

And the razor page is set up as:

```
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync" Context="EditFormContext">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />

...

    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>
```

For the non complex types it works as expected. But for the complex type, the StreetNumberAndName in this case, I'm seeing the following weirdness:

1. When it is empty with the validation message up, and I enter a value using Chrome's auto-fill, when I leave that edit box, I get an additional identical validation message. So I have the same validation message up twice.
2. If it is empty and I enter a value by typing, then when I exit the edit box, the validation message remains.

On item #2 I've found that typing a value in an edit box (non complex type), exiting the edit box removes the validation message. But for a DxComboBox control, the validation message stays up until I click submit. So issue #2 may be a more general issue not specific to a complex type.

Comment: I've just checked to make sure I'm quoting correctly.   I've probably said this before - `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` is not a released or supported product.  Last release was 29-April-2020.  MS's last comment was in June 2021 that they were considering "productionizing" it in Net6.  No one is supporting it: it's almost certainly dead in the water.  In a production environment, I would seriously consider another approach.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The thing is, any other approach requires significant coding on page after page. Probably less work to figure out what's wrong in `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` and fix it.

Comment: Then I wish you good luck.